# Issue writing a DynamicTableEntity to Azure table storage using repository patterns

Tags: c#, .net, azure, repository-pattern, azure-table-storage

CONTEXT:

My aim is to have a couple of DynamicTableEntity that have their own respective tables in Azure table storage. This is so the entities can add fields granularly on the fly should the system need them to.

Currently I am using a repository pattern to interface with/create tables for my (non dynamic) TableEntities. In the repository constructor I use these lines:

> Table = TableClient.GetTableReference(typeof(TEntity).Name);
>   Table.CreateIfNotExists();

To get the entities respective table, and if it does not already exist create it using the supplied TEntity name. (TEntity is constrained to be an ITableEntity).

ISSUE:

Where the name of my table storage is derived from the TEntity.Name supplied, and where DynamicTableEntity is a sealed class that cannot be inherited from, I cannot specify a name for my azure table. Any use of DynamicTableEntity's would end up using the same table called "DynamicTableEntity".

Can you think of anyway that I can specify a table name. I've considered wrapping the DynamicTableEntity in a class as well as looking at attributes

Answer (score 0):

Inside the component where you convert your strong type entity into DynamicTableEntity, you can add a Name property to the DynamicTableEntity using the same value (typeof(TEntity).Name). You can then use the value of this Name property to decide the table.

On the reverse conversion, if you want to convert the DynamicTableEntity back to strong type you can strip that Name property out.

You may also want to put that name to Table reference mapping into a web config / app config file.